# Mongodb new data insert in top

Tags: mongodb, insert

Usually mongodb saves previous data on top. Can we save data as new at the top?

Mean i want to insert my new data on 0 no index every time and pervious data will go down as `Array.unshift()` method...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got you right.

**Within a document:**
This could be helpful [$position](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/position/)

**Within a collection:**
You could just sort by _id descending when accessing the data to get new documents first.